# Property value of null when value is assigned inside a method hooked to the wp action hook

Tags: php, oop

In `my_method()` below, I'm assigning an array of post IDs to the property `$this->post_ids` which is to be used later on in my query args - see `process()`.

If I hook `my_method()` to the `init` action hook, things work but if I hook `my_method()` to the `wp` action hook, things don't work.

When `my_method()` is hooked to `wp`, doing `var_dump( $this->post_ids )` inside `process()` displays `null`.

When `my_method()` is hooked to `init`, doing `var_dump( $this->post_ids )` inside `process()` displays `Array[15]`.

-

```
public function __construct() {
    // This works
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'my_method' ) );

    // This doesn't work.
    add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'my_method' ) );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', array( $this, 'process' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', array( $this, 'process' ) );
}
```

-

```
public function my_method() {
    $this->post_ids = explode( ',', '69,70,71,72,73,80,86,89,90,91,92,93,94,96,169' );
}
```

-

```
public function process() {

    $args = array(
        'offset' => 10,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post__in' => $this->post_ids
    );

    $this->query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Process the query results here...
}
```

**Background info:** The `process()` method handles data sent via an AJAX request. After processing, it sends a response to the browser. For example: `echo json_encode( $response )`

**My question:**

Inside `process()`, why is the value of the `$this->post_ids` property:

- `null` when I hook `my_method()` to `wp`
- `Array[15]` when I hook `my_method()` to `init`?

I don't understand why it is different.

**Update:** The value of `$this->post_ids` is `null` only inside the `process()` method. Could this be because `process()` is running during an AJAX request?

Comment: I think that your are right. `process()` is running during an Ajax request, not during a WP object request. The `wp` action occurs after a WP object has been set up, so it is not available during Ajax requests, so `my_method` is never executed if it is hooked to `wp` action. By the way, don't forget to `exit` at the end of the Ajax processing or use the [`wp_send_json`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) family of functions which sends a json response and performs the exit for you.

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta, it looks that way. It's a pain for me because inside `my_method()` I also need to get the author ID of the author page currently being viewed. But author ID isn't available at the point `init` is run. So I can't hook `my_method()` to `init`. But that's another question :) Thanks again.

Comment: In the `init` action hook, or any other action hook, executed during the Ajax request you won't get the author ID or any other information of the page/post where you send the Ajax request. That is normal. You need to pass that information tin the Ajax request data.

Comment: This particular Ajax call happens after a user has clicked a button so the `init` action hook will be executed before the Ajax request takes place.

Comment: Yes, the `init` action occurs in the Ajax request but the Ajax request is not he request for the page where you send the Ajax from, so the information of that page is not available if you don't send it with Ajax data. Why a particular page should be loaded during an Ajax request? I think you are confused here. Other thing is if you request a particular page via Ajax but this not your situation.

Comment: So am I right in saying every variable I want to use inside `process()` must come from the Ajax script? The part that makes that hard for me to understand is if I do the following inside `my_method()` when it's hooked to `init`... `$this->time = current_time( 'mysql' )`, then `$this->time` is actually available when used inside `process()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17107/discussion-between-cybmeta-and-henrywright).